# What does 'sich in der Bringschuld sehen' mean?

Tags: translation, phrase

I came across the following paragraph in *Der Spiegel*:

> Eine der wichtigsten Fragen ist, wie [Donald] Trump nun mit seiner Partei umgeht. Die Republikaner sind traumatisiert, die alte Garde fühlt sich gedemütigt. Nach Ted Cruz hat jetzt auch noch John Kasich, der letzte Rivale, aufgegeben. **Trump scheint nicht sich in der Bringschuld zu sehen, sondern seine Gegner.** "Ich glaube, ich kann viele in der Partei vereinen", sagt er. "Aber einige will ich auch gar nicht."

Some of the translations of the word *der Bringschuld* in the dictionaries are:

> [debt to be delivered to the creditor]; obligation to provide; debt to be discharged at creditor's domicile

These, however, do not seem to be helpful in understanding the meaning of the phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Bringschuld" can also be used to determine who is obliged to take initiative - In your example, this would be the intended meaning (It is, however, quite a bit arguable whether this was indeed the right choice of words)

> Trump sees himself not obliged to do the first steps to re-unite the Republican party, but rather sees that with his opponents.

Answer (score 4):

In the stricter sense, it actually means, that the party with the *Bringschuld* is obliged to do something, e. g. deliver a payment. In the next step this generalized to other subjects as well, for instance *information*. In your example it was blurred further to simply indicate, who has to take initiative next. So the nearest English counterpiece of *Du hast die Bringschuld* I can think of is

> The ball is in your park.